# How can I get my redirection link accepted by Facebook community standard?

Tags: branch.io

I am using Branch for redirecting users to their corresponding app store but also to track where the user comes from. However I can't find a way to put a trackable Branch link on Instagram or Facebook. It gets rejected not following 'Community Standard'.

So I am in this situation:

`app.myapp.com` => redirection accepted by Community Standard but no tracking link

`app.myapp.com/zJQj4nY6fX?ref=trackingref` => rejected by Commynity Standard.

The ref allows me to do the tracking.

Anyone has a suggestion ? I have also checked at Branch [workaround](https://blog.branch.io/how-to-deep-linking-from-facebook/) but can't really understand what to do in the workaround.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about the issue with posting your link to Facebook. How are you sharing these links in Facebook? When sharing links to Facebook via their newsfeed, messaging features, etc they will block links if they determine the link violates Facebook's community guidelines, links can be flagged as spam and may be blocked from being posted if:

- Facebook detects that the post includes a link to a malicious website
- Attempts were made to post the same link multiple times or in multiple places

You will want to reach out to FB support to get your link unblocked https://www.facebook.com/help.

You also can set up monitoring for all your links using Facebook's Open Graph API. You can ping Facebook's Open Graph servers at regular intervals to check if the link has been blocked and immediately contact Facebook to resolve this issue.

```
curl -X POST \
-F "id={object-url OR object-id}" \
-F "scrape=true" \
-F "access_token={your access token}" \
```

"https://graph.facebook.com"

The API returns OG information for a valid link and fails if the link is blocked by Facebook.

If you are running ad campaigns, I would recommend using Branch's Universal Ads feature with FB Ads as Branch is a FB MMP and this should keep your links from being blocked.

https://docs.branch.io/deep-linked-ads/branch-universal-ads-mobile-tracking
https://docs.branch.io/deep-linked-ads/facebook-ads-overview/#facebook-ads-overview

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello @Sylvia thank you for this very precise answer. Indeed I have several instagram account for different cities on which I share the same link but with different parameters. Is that an against Facebook Community Standards ?